# Carbon::today()->toDateString() is not equals to today date

Tags: php-carbon

For my code:

```
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$compare = Carbon::today()->toDateString() == '2020-12-03' ? 'yes' : 'no';
Log::debug('today '.$today);
Log::debug('compare '.$compare);
```

It return me:

```
2020-12-03
no
```

Anyone can help explain to me why it return 'no' instead of 'yes'.

Comment: is there a timezone defined somewhere?

Comment: There isn't have timezone defined in my function, it only a plain function that return true or false only.

Comment: `Carbon::now()->toDateString() === Carbon::today()->toDateString()` So a better question is: was `2020-12-03` the correct date in the default timezone you're running with PHP. Check `date_default_timezone_get()` and if the date/time is what you expected in this timezone. My recommendation is to always set it to UTC `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` and create specific object with user timezone dynamically it's the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

toDateString() function returns string & your date is not in string format.

[image: Example of string comparison]

[image: Another example of comparison]

Comment: Carbon::today()->toDateString() == "2020-12-03" ? 'yes' : 'no'; or Carbon::today()->toDateString() == '2020-12-03' ? 'yes' : 'no'; is not working too.

Comment: @Bryan I tested the above example also & it displays a proper output. Let me know where you are facing this issue

Comment: facing this issue in my queue function.